# Custom static files on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, static-files

I opened http static files on programs&features, but in Visual Studio my libraries are working but on iis my website's template will crash

The project cannot see bootstrap js jQuery libraries etc....

There are include my project's node_modules folder.

I included them like this:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder CustomStaticFiles(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "node_modules");
    var options = new StaticFileOptions{FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path),RequestPath = "/modules"};
    app.UseStaticFiles(options);
    return app;
}
```

Program cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.CustomStaticFiles();
```

Thank you for spend time for my problem....

Comment: Did you check what Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is returning when you run your app in IIS?

Comment: tyx. how can i get that??

Comment: Attach [the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour). Or add trace logging somewhere, possibly using a library such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/).

Comment: After publishing the asp.net core application to IIS, please make sure the application contains the `node_modules` folder. Besides, as mason said, check the current directory path.